Show that for integers $x$ and $y$, $x-y$ is even if and only if $x$ and $y$ are of the same parity.
The current problem I'm working on is from the book Mathematical Proofs: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics, Fourth edition by Gary Chartrand, Albert D. Polimeni, and Ping Zhang. What follows is the problem statement and below that is my solution.
Exercise 3.30. Show that for integers $x$ and $y$, $x-y$ is even if and only if $x$ and $y$ are of the same parity.
This question is related, but only discusses something related to the first implication, although I'm not sure if that matters too much given my work below?

For $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$, there are two statements to prove:

If $x-y$ is even, then $x$ and $y$ are of the same parity.
If $x$ and $y$ are of the same parity, then $x-y$ is even.

Here is what I have:
To prove the first implication, we take the contrapositive, letting $x$ and $y$ be integers of opposite parity. Without loss of generality, let $x$ be even and $y$ be odd, so $x=2m$ and $y=2n+1$ for some $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then,
$$ \begin{align}
x-y & = \left( 2m \right) - \left( 2n+1 \right) \\
 &  = 2m -2n-1 \\
 & = 2\left( m-n-1 \right) +1.
\end{align} $$
Since $m-n-1$ is an integer, $x-y$ is odd. To prove the second implication, we divide it into two subcases. First, assume $x$ and $y$ are both even integers, so $x=2a$ and $y=2b$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore,
$$ \begin{align}
x-y  & = \left( 2a \right) -\left( 2b \right)  \\
 & =2\left( a-b \right) .
\end{align} $$
It follows that $x-y$ is odd, because $a-b$ is an integer. For the second case, assume $x$ and $y$ are both odd integers, where $x=2p+1$ and $y=2q+1$ for $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence,
$$ \begin{align}
x-y & = \left( 2p+1 \right) - \left(2q+1 \right)  \\
 & = 2p-2q \\
 &  = 2\left( p-q \right).
\end{align}$$
It must be that $x-y$ is even, because $p-q$ is an integer. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

I don't see any obvious issues with my work, but I'm new to this.

Looks fine to me!

"It follows that $x-y$ is even, because $a-b$ is..." Beside this, your proof is perfect.

Awesome! Thank you both so much! Should I edit my post, @azif00? Or is it worth keeping it as is?

First proof is valid if you know "odd" is the same as "not even"

Another way to reason here might be to write $x=2q_1+r_1$ where $q_1,r_1$ are the quotient/remainder when divided by $2$, and similarly $y=2q_2+r_2$. Then $x-y=2(q_1-q_2)+r_1-r_2$, so $x-y$ is a multiple of 2 iff $r_1=r_2$.
